# Duplicate value in NavigationView header after updating header text

Tags: android, xml, android-navigationview

After updating my header text and image in NavigationView header, I'm getting duplicate value in NavigationView header.

Here is my code part

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
    implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

boolean doubleBackToExitPressedOnce = false;
SQLiteHelper dbHelper;
String setName, setMail;
AlertDialog.Builder builder, builder_verify;
public static int count = 0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    dbHelper = new SQLiteHelper(getApplicationContext());
    builder_verify = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);        

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();     

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
    View hView =  navigationView.inflateHeaderView(R.layout.nav_header_main);
    ImageView iv = (ImageView) hView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    TextView headerName = (TextView) hView.findViewById(R.id.txtName);
    TextView headerMail = (TextView) hView.findViewById(R.id.textEmail);

    iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.logo);
    headerName.setText("TEST");
    headerMail.setText("test@gmail.com");        
}    
}
```

In the above code i have added view to update my header text. Also i have added main XML code below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:openDrawer="start">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/flContent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</LinearLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
    app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Also added navigation header layout

nav_header_main.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="@dimen/nav_header_height"
android:background="@drawable/side_nav_bar"
android:gravity="bottom"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/nav_header_vertical_spacing"
    android:src="@drawable/logo"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtName"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/nav_header_vertical_spacing"
    android:text="Sample"
    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body2"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textEmail"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Sample Inc." /></LinearLayout>
```

Also i have added the screenshot for reference

[image: HearderView]

Right now, I don't see any possibilities of changing the headerview. Any suggestions to avoid duplicate header text and image?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Good question.

The fix is to instead of inflating header(it's already inflated!) by `navigationView.inflateHeaderView(R.layout.nav_header_main);` get it from `NavigationView` via `getHeaderView(int index)` method and then fill it.

Here's the code to run:

```
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
    View hView =  navigationView.getHeaderView(0);
    ImageView iv = (ImageView) hView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    TextView headerName = (TextView) hView.findViewById(R.id.txtName);
    TextView headerMail = (TextView) hView.findViewById(R.id.txtEmail);
    iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.logo);
```

Comment: Thank you so much :) Konstantin Loginov

Answer (score 5):

In xml fie you have already set

```
 app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
```

for `NavigationView` and again in java class you'r inflating your view with

```
View hView =  navigationView.inflateHeaderView(R.layout.nav_header_main);
```

So there is a duplicate values in `NavigationView`.

Comment: Thank you for your valuable reply Piyush Gupta and make me realize where i was made a mistake

Answer (score 0):

I have a easy solution for this issue and it is worked for me.
Before adding header views we must remove current header views from navigation drawer. This is the code snippet.

```
if (navigationView != null) {
   for (int i = 0; i < navigationView.getHeaderCount(); i++) {
   if (navigationView.getHeaderView(i) != null)
   navigationView.getHeaderView(i).setVisibility(View.GONE);
   }
   addHeaderLayout(navigationView);
  }
```